# Cannot test login function on flask app with flask-testing

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-testing

I have a Flask app that I am writing tests for using Flask Testing. I have no trouble running the app and logging in/out, but writing a test for the login function has backfired. I get the following error: "Exception: No user_loader has been installed for this LoginManager. Add one with the 'LoginManager.user_loader' decorator." However, I have defined a user_loader decorator in the User model (see this [flask-login example](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/minimal-flask-login-example.html)). Any idea what's wrong?

My code is:

User model in models.py:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

from app import db, login_manager

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    """
    Create a User table
    """

    # Ensures table will be named in plural and not in singular
    # as is the name of the model
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    file = db.relationship('File', backref='users')

    @property
    def password(self):
        """
        Prevent password from being accessed
        """
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute.')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        """
        Set password to a hashed password
        """
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        """
        Check if hashed password matches actual password
        """
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    # Set up user_loader
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User: {}>'.format(self.username)
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, DOCUMENTS, DATA, configure_uploads

# local imports
from config import app_config

# db variable initialization
db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_message = "You must be logged in to access this page."
login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    db.init_app(app)

    # Code for login manager
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    # Code for db migrations
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    # Bootstrap
    Bootstrap(app)

    # Debugger
    DebugToolbarExtension(app)

    # # Configure the data uploading via Flask-Uploads
    # data_set = UploadSet('data_set', DOCUMENTS, DATA)
    # configure_uploads(app, data_set)

    from app import models

    # Register Blueprints
    from .admin import admin as admin_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(admin_blueprint, url_prefix='/admin')

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    from .home import home as home_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)

    return app
```

tests.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_testing import TestCase
import app.__init__ as app_init
from app import db, login_manager
from app.models import User

class RenderbotTestCase(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        app = app_init.create_app('testing')
        app.config.update(
            SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://testingdburl'
        )
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        self.c = self.app.test_client()
        db.init_app(self.app)
        db.create_all()
        self.first_user =  User(email="test@test.com",
                        username="Test",
                        first_name="Tom",
                        last_name="Test",
                        password="test")
        db.session.add(self.first_user)
        db.session.commit()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    def login(self, email, password):
        return self.c.post(url_for('auth.login'), data=dict(
            email=email,
            password=password
        ), follow_redirects=True)

    def test_login(self):

        rv = self.login('test@test.com', 'test')
        self.assert_redirects(rv, url_for('home.dashboard')), 'Unable to login'
```